# XNA MediaPlayer ContentLoadException was unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, media-player

I want to use the `MediaPlayer` object to play one background song. Everything is fine until I try to start the program.

I have seen people using only two lines of code in order to play a song, this is what I do in the `LoadContent` method:

```
    Song song = Content.Load<Song>("song");"song_title"
    MediaPlayer.Play(song_title);
```

I get this in error

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error loading "song". File contains Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect but trying to load as Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song.
```

Comment: Did you set the `type` in the `content processor` setting?  _[Would you like to know more?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/eddbf4d2-76b8-4507-ab2c-047eac069185/cant-load-soundeffect)_

Comment: In the examples I found they where using Song as type and so have I so yes I have set the type

Comment: What is the file format of song?  also what is "song_title"?

Comment: The file format is WAV and the song_title is the song title so the name of the song is "song_title.WAV".

Comment: Try a rebuild after setting the correct type. Looks like your XNB file is a `SoundEffect`. In fact, open up your XNB file in a hex editor and see what it says it is.